# Android using Non-breaking characters

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to have a non breaking dashes or space in `strings.xml` file in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. It is possible to use the following characters:

non breaking dash: `&#8209;`
non breaking space: `&#160;`